# How to check interrupt vectors

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, hardware, virtualization

How can I check interrupt vectors? The one I want to check is PMI(performance monitoring interrupt). Previously assume it may be the same as NMI, cuz their number is always the same in /proc/interrupt on my computer. Now I realize I am wrong. So can someone tell me how to check its vector, and maybe what is type? Is it a external interrupt, NMI, or some other type?

I am doing is first identifying PMI in VMM, then inject it into guest.

Thanks.

Comment: It is Core i7 3160QM, Ivy Bridge.